# What encoding in emacs corresponds to LaTeX's ansinew?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding, latex, ansi

As the title says:

Which encoding do I have to choose in emacs long list of encodings (accessible via e.g., change for saving file: `C-x RET f`), that it matches `ansinew` in LaTeX as given by:

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Should be [`windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`inputenc` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/inputenc.pdf) you can read

> `ansinew` Windows 3.1 ANSI encoding, extension of Latin-1 (synonym for
>   `cp1252`).

In Emacs `cp1252` is an alias of `windows-1252`, so you can use both of them.